# How do I pass a parameter to a js script?

Tags: javascript

How do I define and pass a value to a script tag from the html file?

for example to do something like below where I want to pass the value of "myparameter"

```
<script src="app.js" myparameter="myvalue" type="module"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your html like this:

```
<script src="app.js" myparameter="myvalue" type="module"></script>
```

Inside js script:

```
document.currentScript.getAttribute('myparameter'); //myvalue
```

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate; to better maintain the quality of the site, please don't answer and vote/flag as such (if you have the privilege).